# Disputed "Not an answer" flag?

Tags: discussion, flagging, answers

I flagged [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/179343/18944) as "Not an answer" after reading the [guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81392) linked to from the [help section](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

I felt the answer could certainly be flagged based on this criterion:

> A user wants to reply to the OP, an answerer or a commenter, but
>   doesn't have enough rep, and instead of thinking "maybe there's a
>   reason I'm not allowed to post comments," ignores the help text about
>   what an answer is.

and potentially also on this one:

> A user has a related issue and isn't aware of the "Ask Question"
>   button.

(since the user seems to be having trouble implementing the accepted answer and may be looking for help).

However, my flag seems to have been disputed with no reason given, so I'm now wondering what the problem was?

Have I misunderstood flagging in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a flag is marked as disputed, it means that a user (not a community moderator) who has access to the review queue for those flags marked it as not useful.

IMO, it seems an answer that corrects the code given from another answer, rather than a reply to a user who answered, which would be a question for a user who answered or a reply for a comment left under his/her answer from a user who answered the question.
Certainly, the answer would need the user to make more explicit to which answer he is referring, and give more details.

In short, you didn't misunderstand anything. It is just that, at that level, it is matter of point of views.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on the "disputed" status. I agree that the answer is intended to be a correction for the accepted answer, but aren't comments/edits the appropriate places for corrections; not new answers that don't form a complete solution to the question? In this case it's also questionable whether the proposed correction is even valid since the user says the problem they're having could be due to their own code or other code elsewhere. The code in the accepted answer seems to work perfectly for me on a fresh Drupal install without needing any modifications.

Comment: It depends all from how the answer has been seen. I could see it as "the previous answer is wrong; this is the correct answer." If the answer is just "the other answer is correct, except for these details […]." I agree that is more a comment than an answer. It happens that flags are wrongly handled; sometimes there are too much flags to handle them correctly.